# JS: String "1, 2, 5" to Array[1, 2, 5]?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm a js beginner and want convert a string e.g. "1, 4, 7" to an array [1, 4, 7].

I need something like the opposite of the function join

Comment: use split function

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const convert = str => str.split(',').map(p=>+p)

console.log(convert("1, 4, 7"))
```

Comment: Just use `.map(Number)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 >> "1, 4, 7".split(", ").map(num => +num)
 >> [1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Just use `.map(Number)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let s = "1, 4, 7";

let a = JSON.parse(`[${s}]`);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var str = '1, 2, 3';`
`var = str.split(", ");`

by splitting the string, it will be return as an array missing the delimiter... in this case ", " (comma and space)

this will not work as expected if `str = '1,2, 3';`

for that you will need a regular expression...
`var = str.split(/, ?/);`